# Farseer: Collision detection, but without further body interaction

Tags: collision-detection, farseer

I have a ball that rolls through a maze-like world. I want an event to rise if the ball crosses a certain line. I don't want to place a texture at this line and I don't want the ball to be deflected. How can it be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Farseer 3.3.1 you can create a body, say `sensorLine` with a fixture that has `Fixture.IsSensor` set to `true`. That way the fixture won't take part in collisions. You can then poll the fixture for overlapping bodies by iterating over `sensorLine.ContactList` or you can register a callback to the `World.ContactManager.BeginContact` event of your world instance.

It sounds like `EdgeShape` would be the kind of shape to use for the fixture in `sensorLine`. If you only create a Farseer body, nothing will be visible on screen, so you need not worry about placing textures anywhere.